# Como concatenar string com nulo sem verificar explicitamente?

Tags: java, string

Quando tento concatenar uma `String` que, na verdade, é nula com uma *string* válida (por exemplo, "a"), obtenho o valor `nulla`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
String a = "a";
String b = null;
System.out.println(b + a);
```

Eu queria que a saída fosse apenas "a". Há alguma maneira de fazer isso sem verificar se a `String` é `null`?

Comment: Não faz sentido algum concatenar com nulo, o recomendao é sempre verificar  se alguma das variaveis é nula antes de tentar concatenar.

Comment: É você que controla o valor da String b? Não é interessante abusar do null . Frequentemente quando algo retorna nulo, deveria ter retornado um objeto padrão (no caso, uma string vazia) ou lançado uma exceção.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que procurava saber? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora? Se não, precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Não deveria tentar concatenar um nulo com um texto. Até acho que o Java deveria ou proibir a concatenação neste caso, ou adotar uma *string* vazia quando encontra um nulo (cada um tem prós e contras). Como não é assim, a solução é esta:

```
System.out.println((b == null ? "" : b) + a);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e4KszK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hyxxfsey-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/ConcatNull.java).

Obviamente que pode criar um método utilitário para fazer isto de forma genérica e usar sempre que necessário.

Comment: Mas o java lança um nullpointerexception se tenta fazer operação com null, isso já não seria uma forma de "proibir"?

Comment: @diegofm não neste caso. Só para você ver que nem é coisa do `println()`: http://ideone.com/KctKc9 Deve haver alguma regra de coerção que determine isto. Sei que no C# h´pa uma regra que transforma em `""`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/2E1mmK

Comment: Nossa, então a jre recebe null e, ao concatenar, transforma em string. Que coisa mais estranha hehe

Answer (score 4):

Se garante que `a` tem um valor e somente `b` pode vir nula, pode seguir o que foi respondido pelo Maniero.

Se não tiver certeza e/ou precise testar um número maior de strings, pode ser mais interessante utilizar [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) para verificar se um objeto é nulo. E se este for, retornar algum valor pré-definido que não atrapalhará a concatenação (uma string vazia talvez?!) :

```
public static String get(String string){
   return Optional.ofNullable(string).orElse("");
}
```

Utilizando:

```
String a = "a", b = null, c = "c";    

get(a) + get(b); // "a"
get(a) + get(b) + get(c); // "ac"
get(b); // ""
```

---

#### [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/kvbdh4)

Comment: Era disto que eu estava falando :)

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que ao invés de setar uma variável do tipo *String* como "null" você deveria setá-la como "". Por exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "a";
    String b = "";
    System.out.println(a+b);
}
```

Assim ele já te retorna o correto;

Comment: Não me leve a mal mas não vejo sua resposta como solução para o problema. Acredito que o exemplo da pergunta foi para fins demonstrativos, e se ele não tiver controle do que vem nessa variavel? E se o valor dela for definido por outro método? Enfim, a sua sugestão peca e várias hipoteses como solução da duvida.